# VPS Server Thousands of Security Audit Failure Events

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I am new to managing a hosted Windows vps and in the past 4 days my security event log shows about 35,000 Events as:
Audit Failure "An account failed to log on."
These appear to be recurring attempts to gain access using a variety of user names. This is a Win 2008 R2 vps.

A few questions:
1 - Is this normal to receive this level of login attempts?
2 - Is there any way to block this?
3 - What is the best way to prevent one of these attempts from gaining access and taking over my server?

Any suggestions welcomed - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer has a publicity accessible IP, then it's *in the wild*  and yes, it's normal.  This is a sad & unfortunate reality.

What services do you have exposed to the internet?  smb/cifs/rdp/rras ?  You'll need to limit your attack surface by shutting down services that aren't needed, or beefing up your firewall rules.

Comment: Well - the services running and allowing public through the firewall right now are core networking, DFS Management, RDP, HTTPS, HTTP, and a Subversion server. Can any of these be shut down?

Answer (score 0):

Firewall off the RDP port so that only your IP can connect to it (assuming you have a static IP).

Comment: How do I do that or where would I set this?